# Nginx not redirect all requests to index.html

Tags: nginx, routes, devops, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am trying to redirect all requests to index.html on Nginx but it's not redirecting.

> Working -> https://www.example.com/reviews

> Not Working -> https://www.example.com/reviews/

in 2nd URL if you see in last due to "/" Slash it's not working.

I am using the following settings in Nginx settings

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx considers directories (URLs with a trailing slash) separately from normal files. Try this instead:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```